# Maven web application - ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I create my first Maven web application which use database.
When I use maven clean and install And when I run on Tomcat server I get this:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet UserController
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.store.connector.UserController
```

I dont know what is the problem. 
After maven install, my UserController.class can be found in
**target -> NewStore-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> WEB-INF -> classes -> com -> store -> connector -> UserController.class**

My web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        version="3.0"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

  <display-name>NewStore</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UserController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UserController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.store.connector.UserController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UserController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UserController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>NewStore</groupId>
    <artifactId>NewStore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>NewStore</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-alpha-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Basicly UserController.java can be found in NewStore -> src -> main -> java -> com -> store -> connector

UserController.java

```
package com.store.connector;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.store.dao.UserDao;

public class UserController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String LIST_USER = "listUser.jsp";
    private UserDao dao;

    public UserController() {
        super();
        dao = new UserDao();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listUser")) {
            forward = LIST_USER;
            request.setAttribute(forward, dao.getAllUsers());
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, it's nearly always better to use a framework like Spring MVC or JAX-RS than to manage the low-level Servlet API yourself. How are you running this app? If you're not using the packaged war, are you putting the target directory on Tomcat's classpath?

Comment: Did you install war file from target directory into tomcat?

Comment: When i created this maven project, i chose war. In xampp, Apache and MySQL is running. When i run this project i select run as -> run on server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the Maven dependencies, so remove those. And add to the `servlet-api` the following: `<scope>provided</scope>`, since the container already has, though you need it to compile your code.

Comment: Yeah maven dependencies didn't need. And <scope>provided</scope> didn't work. :S